# Multipart post with ionic native http

Tags: ionic5

We are trying to post multipart data with file and blob objet using ionic native http post. But we are not able to make it work. Explored many forums for similar kind of issue and many says native http doesn’t support multipart with formdata.

Could someone help us to resolve this?

Note: We don’t want to use angular http client and we know it works with that. Thanks in advace.

Comment: Can you please share with us what you have tried so far?